# Как анимировать заливку в полосе прогресса SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Я хочу использовать изображение SVG для страницы пожертвований.
Мне необходимо заполнить цветом все изображение сердца (а не только границы)
в направлении снизу вверх. Как изменить направление заполнения?

Пример: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kimmobrunfeldt/dnLLgm5o/)

```html
<div id="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
              <path fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" stroke="#bbb" d="M81.495,13.923c-11.368-5.261-26.234-0.311-31.489,11.032C44.74,13.612,29.879,8.657,18.511,13.923  C6.402,19.539,0.613,33.883,10.175,50.804c6.792,12.04,18.826,21.111,39.831,37.379c20.993-16.268,33.033-25.344,39.819-37.379  C99.387,33.883,93.598,19.539,81.495,13.923z"/>
              <path id="heart-path" fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="3" stroke="#ED6A5A" d="M81.495,13.923c-11.368-5.261-26.234-0.311-31.489,11.032C44.74,13.612,29.879,8.657,18.511,13.923  C6.402,19.539,0.613,33.883,10.175,50.804c6.792,12.04,18.826,21.111,39.831,37.379c20.993-16.268,33.033-25.344,39.819-37.379  C99.387,33.883,93.598,19.539,81.495,13.923z"/>
          </svg>
</div>

// progressbar.js@1.0.0 version is used
// Docs: http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.0/

var bar = new ProgressBar.Path('#heart-path', {
easing: 'easeOut',
duration: 5400
});

bar.set(0);
bar.animate(1.0);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to animate fill instead of path in an SVG progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42672537/7394871) от участника  [@Shahar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255370/shahar).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672537/how-to-animate-fill-instead-of-path-in-an-svg-progress-bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда делаются пожертвования вы можете использовать маску и перемещать ее вверх от основания сердца.
[EDIT]: Включается интервал таймера для анимации заливки.
См. Пример ниже:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<div style='width:200px;height:200px;'>
  <svg  x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
  <defs>
    <mask id="heart">
        <path fill=white d="M81.495,13.923c-11.368-5.261-26.234-0.311-31.489,11.032C44.74,13.612,29.879,8.657,18.511,13.923  C6.402,19.539,0.613,33.883,10.175,50.804c6.792,12.04,18.826,21.111,39.831,37.379c20.993-16.268,33.033-25.344,39.819-37.379  C99.387,33.883,93.598,19.539,81.495,13.923z"/>
    </mask>
</defs>
  <rect id=heartRect x=0 y="100%"  fill=red width="100%" height="100%"  mask="url(#heart)" />
  <path id=heartPath stroke="red" fill=none stroke-width=3 d="M81.495,13.923c-11.368-5.261-26.234-0.311-31.489,11.032C44.74,13.612,29.879,8.657,18.511,13.923  C6.402,19.539,0.613,33.883,10.175,50.804c6.792,12.04,18.826,21.111,39.831,37.379c20.993-16.268,33.033-25.344,39.819-37.379  C99.387,33.883,93.598,19.539,81.495,13.923z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
 <button onClick=donateAnimate()>Donate Animate()</button>
 <script>
//---button---
function donateAnimate()
{
var iT = setInterval(donate, 50 )
var Donations=0
function donate()
{
     if(Donations>=1)
    clearInterval(iT);
    var bb=heartPath.getBBox()
    var bby=bb.y
    var bbh=bb.height
    //---bottom of heart---
    var heartBase=bby+bbh

    if(Donations<1)
    {
        Donations+=.05
        var percent=(1-Donations)*heartBase
        heartRect.setAttribute("y",percent)
    }

}

}
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Это потрясающе! Можно заполнить сердце анимацией? Медленно заполняется. @Shahar
Я добавил интервал таймер. Для начала анимации нажмите на  кнопку `Donate`  @Francis Hemsher

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42675281/7394871) от участника  [@Francis Hemsher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3102976/francis-hemsher).</sub>

Comment: вы что сами задали вопрос и сами ответили ?

Comment: лучше бы на svg-art.ru выложили бы ! я там постоянный читатель уже с пол года там , я даже не знал что вы админ того сайта

Comment: @Geyan спасибо за оценку сайта. Про ассоциацию между enSO и ruSO почитайте по ссылке http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: я знаком с ruSO и EnSo

Comment: Александр, привет....  +++++

Comment: @Air Привет! Благодарю. Долго жить будешь, только что вспоминал тебя, что давно не заглядываешь в SVG

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете сделать это с помощью фильтра. Вот что оживляет заливку:

```html
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <defs>
    <filter id="fillpartial" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
      <feFlood x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" flood-color="red" />
      <feOffset dy="0.5">
        <animate attributeName="dy" from="1" to=".5" dur="3s" />
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <polygon filter="url(#fillpartial)" points="165.000, 185.000, 188.511, 197.361, 184.021, 171.180,
 203.042, 152.639,
 176.756, 148.820,
 165.000, 125.000,
 153.244, 148.820,
 126.958, 152.639,
 145.979, 171.180,
 141.489, 197.361,
 165.000, 185.000" style="fill:white;stroke:red;" />
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Outlining and partially filling an SVG Shape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29382938/7394871) от участника  [@Michael Mullany](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271353/michael-mullany).</sub>